# Set a php link url and generate pdf for that file output

Tags: php, pdf

I am not able to generate pdf for my php output.
If I am giving this,it is generating pdf for google.

```
include_once('phpToPDF.php') ;
phptopdf_url('http://google.com','pdf/', 'my_pdf_filename.pdf');
echo "<a href='pdf/my_pdf_filename.pdf'>Download PDF</a>";
```

But if I am giving my local file url, I am getting a corrupted pdf file.

```
include_once('phpToPDF.php') ;
phptopdf_url('example.php','pdf/', 'my_pdf_filename.pdf');    
echo "<a href='pdf/my_pdf_filename.pdf'>Download PDF</a>";
```

OR

```
include_once('phpToPDF.php') ;
phptopdf_url('http://localhost:8080/example.php','pdf/', 'my_pdf_filename.pdf');
echo "<a href='pdf/my_pdf_filename.pdf'>Download PDF</a>";
```

Can any body tell why I am not getting result or is there another way to do it..?
Any help will b appreciated.

Comment: My guess would be `phptopdf_url` api needs `http://` and doesn't accept ports.

Comment: @l'L'l: no its not working friend.

Comment: What isn't? Try using only `http://localhost/example.php` or `http://127.0.0.1/example.php`

Comment: @l'L'l: Hey pdf file is getting downloaded but it giving error for :
The requested URL /example.php was not found on this server.